# How do I declare a default parser for Rest Assured 3.0.3 (using Java and TestNG)?

Tags: java, json, api, parsing, rest-assured

Good day folks,

I am an admittedly novice Java programmer but I take care to research docs and FAQ's to try to get past issues.  This is a problem that I have not been able to overcome, however.  I am using RestAssured (version 3.0.3, as pulled by Maven) and cannot get RestAssured to parse "text/plain" content (rather, I cannot get Java to compile the code to do so).

This compiles but gives an error:

```
import static io.restassured.RestAssured.*;
import static io.restassured.matcher.RestAssuredMatchers.*;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.*;

import static io.restassured.module.jsv.JsonSchemaValidator.*;

import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;

public class TestNG2 {

/*
   userName, passWord and server defined here as protected static Strings
*/
    @Test
    public void filter_Asset(){

        given().
            auth().basic(userName, passWord).
        when().
            get ("http://" + server +"/api/filter?type=$tAsset").
        then().
            statusCode(200).
            body("count", greaterThan(0));
    }
}
```

The error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected response body to be verified as JSON, HTML or XML but content-type 'text/plain' is not supported out of the box.
>   Try registering a custom parser using:
>      RestAssured.registerParser("text/plain", );

However, when I try to include the following line in the filter_Asset test:

```
RestAssured.registerParser("text/plain", Parser.JSON);
```

The code will not compile with the following complaint:

> java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
>     RestAssured cannot be resolved
>     Parser cannot be resolved to a variable

I receive similar complaints when I try to use the following declaration:

```
RestAssured.defaultParser = Parser.JSON;
```

For what it's worth, I am working on a Windows 7, 64-bit machine.  Using Eclipse Neon.3 (4.6.3) and my JDK is 1.8_131

I've consulted the RestAssured usage and documentation pages, believe am importing the packages correctly, etc.  Am I making a rookie error somewhere?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It was a rookie mistake!

In addition to statically importing the class methods, the compiler also required importing of the following classes:

```
import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import io.restassured.parsing.Parser;
```

After those declarations, I was able to register the default Parser in the filter_Asset test:

RestAssured.registerParser("text/plain", Parser.JSON);